# import pgpy ImportError: No module named pgpy

Tags: python, node.js, docker

I am using node docker image, and installed python3 on top of it using Dockerfile:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:16
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install pgpy
RUN alias pip=pip3
RUN alias python=python3
.
.
.
```

As you can see I have installed `pgpy`.
But when I am importing the module in **py** file, I am getting this error: `ImportError: No module named pgpy`

**decryption.py**

```
import pgpy
.
.
.
```

Can you pls help, what would be the issue?

Comment: Maybe you have different python versions. Check modules with e.g.: python -m pip list

Comment: I have two versions on my docker
`python --version  > Python 2.7.16` `python3 --version > Python 3.7.3`

The command `python -m pip list` is giving me an error `/usr/bin/python: No module named pip` @MarcoF.

Comment: try "pip list" or "pip3 list". I think your script is running with the wrong python version which don't have the module installed.

Comment: Yes, it worked after i used python3 instead of python. Thank you @MarcoF.

Answer (score 0):

I have two python versions installed,`python --version  > Python 2.7.16` `python3 --version > Python 3.7.3`

After changing from `python` to `python3` while running the script, it worked.